# Tablesorter and surnames

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

This seems like it should be easy to do...

```
<table>
    <tr><td>Name</td><td>Number</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Joe Bloggs</td><td>10</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Joe Adams</td><td>12</td></tr>
</table>
```

Using `jquery.tablesorter`, when clicking the name column I want it to sort by the surname portion of the first column, rather than the default which is the forename.

I know it could be done by just reversing from PHP first so `Adams, Joe`; but that looks horrible and seems clunky.

Can this be done with a custom sort?

Comment: isn't it confusing? by clicking name u expect it to sort by name. by clicking number you can sort by the number.

Comment: I agree with Sagiv, this seems like a confusing behaviour. Would it not be better to include surname as a separate column so people can choose to sort by FN or SN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, you should listen to the suggestion of the two comments by Rory and Sargiv as it will create confusing behavior, but if you still insist to do that you can add a custom parser like following

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
        // set a unique id
        id: 'surname',
        is: function(s) {
            // return false so this parser is not auto detected
            return false;
        },
        format: function(s) {

            var parts = s.split(" ");
           // alert(parts[1]);
            // return surname here
            return parts[1];
        },
        // set type, either numeric or text
        type: 'text'
    });
```

then add this as parser for name column like this

```
$('table').tablesorter({
    // include zeba widgets
    widgets: ['zebra'],
    headers: {
                0: {
                    sorter:'surname'
                }
            }

});
```

Here is the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/2TZAn/1/ , check by clicking on name heading, ignore other fields, they are there because I edited an existing fiddle.

here is the plugin page on custom parser http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-parsers.html